# Why did Yelena say, "You're Welcome" here?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow, black-widow-2021

In *Black Widow* (2021), Natasha is driving her car with Yelena. Meanwhile, a biker from behind is shooting at them:

> Yelena: Okay, you got a plan, or shall I just stay duck-and-cover?
>
> Natasha: Yeah, my plan was to drive us away.
>
> Yelena: That's a shit plan.

Then, Yelena kicks the car's door off so that it can disable the biker:

> Yelena: **You're Welcome**.

Why did Yelena say, "You're Welcome" here?

Comment: In response to a hypothetical "thank you"

Answer (score 6):

This is an [*ironic statement*](https://writer.com/blog/irony). Yelena gets the two of them out of a difficult situation. She thinks Natasha ought to express gratitude (or respect for her cleverness).

When Natasha doesn't say anything, Yelena says "you're welcome" to emphasize the fact that she believes she's [owed a 'thank you'](https://jezebel.com/the-sarcastic-pointed-youre-welcome-a-doormats-nightm-5234555).

Comment: A good answer. I've removed the meta-commentary on whether you think it's a good fit for the site or not